# PDF of numbers from linear congruential random numbers

Tags: python, math, random

I am writing a python code to create a probability distribution of numbers generated by the **Linear Congruential random numbers** between 0 and 1. I am not getting the density plot I expected. Shoudn't it be a rectangle of height 1 and span in x from 0 to 1?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m=2**31       #these numbers are same as used by C in rand()
a=1103515245
c=12345
n = 10000
x = np.zeros(n)
x[0]=1          #Seed

for i in range(n-1):
    x[i+1] = ((a*x[i]+c)%m)/m   #Divided by m so that numbers are scaled to the range [0,1]

plt.hist(x,density=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divide term `/m` throws `x[i+1]` into the range `[0, 1)`, which breaks the form of the linear congruential generator.  Try separating the code into a "generator" and "normalized" parts (here, `y` and `x[i]` respectively):

```
y = x[0]
for i in range(n-1):
    y = (a*y+c)%m
    x[i+1] = y/m
```